# VueJS Input Binding with Nested Data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a scenario, where I have some data in my state and some input fields in my view. Which data property is bound to which input field is decided by another data property.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="details[fields.one]">
  <input v-model="details[fields.two]">
  <input v-model="details[fields.three]">
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    d: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    details: {
      a: 'aa',
      b: 'bb',
      c: {
        x: 'xx'
      }
    },
    fields: {
      one:'a',
      two: 'b',
      three: 'c.x'
    }
  }
});
```

As you can see the 'details' data property is to be bound to the three input fields. But the details of field names are in the 'fields' data property.  **The binding of `one:'a'` and `two: 'b'` works great. However, `'fields.three'` fails, because the details data in c is nested.** How can I correct this?

Here is a fiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/n17n7b21/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `fields.three` is an object and not a scalar value, you can not bind it to your input. One thing you can do is to create a function that checks if `fields.one`, `fields.two` and `fields.three` are each simple objects or have nested object.

You can use this function:

```
det (param) {
    let strlen = param.length
        if(1 === strlen){
    return param
  }
  let split = param.split('.')

  let details = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.details))
  for (var key in details) {
    if(key == split[0]){
      for (var key2 in details[key]) {
       return details[key][key2]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And bind your models to this function with param:

Here is a full working demo https://jsfiddle.net/n17n7b21/6/

Comment: thanks so much. This does bind the initial value correctly, but then when I change the value in input field, it doesn't change the data in my data. see here: https://jsfiddle.net/n17n7b21/7/ How do I correct this?

Comment: In that case you don't need a model. check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/n17n7b21/8/ - it is basically what v-model does under the hood. So, it's still v-model but more dynamic

Comment: This works great! Thanks. However it updates 'fields' values when input value changes. Instead, is it possible to update 'details' values?

Comment: Well, you can use this https://jsfiddle.net/n17n7b21/10/ but it would be a hack since I am hardcoding `details.c.x`. It would make your app and the logic much easier if you use arrays instead of object. ex: instead of `details:{}` you can do `details:[]` and put either values or objects inside the array.  or check this one https://jsfiddle.net/n17n7b21/12/ it works without hardcoding but you have to add another method `update` it works for field 1 and 2, you can add a small code for the third one (just detect if field is one string or not like the det() method

Answer (score 3):

This won't work because the `details` object has no property with the key `"c.x"`.

I would recommend you restructure your data model into a flat object (without any nested objects) to make this easier to manage.

If you must have nested properties, then you will have to facilitate the reading and writing to these properties via helper methods:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    details: {
      a: 'a value',
      b: {
       a: 'b.a value',
      },
    },
    fields: {
      one: 'a',
      two: 'b.a',
    },
  },

  computed: {
    state() {
      return JSON.stringify(this.details, '\n', 2);
    },
  },

  methods: {
    getValue(object, path) {
      let obj = object;
      for (const key of path.split('.')) {
       obj = obj[key];
      }
      
      return obj;
    },
    
    setValue(object, path, value) {
      const keys = path.split('.');
      let obj = object;
      for (let i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
       obj = obj[keys[i]];
      }
      
      obj[keys[keys.length - 1]] = value;
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue/dev/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input :value="getValue(details, fields.one)" @input="setValue(details, fields.one, $event.target.value)">
  <input :value="getValue(details, fields.two)" @input="setValue(details, fields.two, $event.target.value)">
  <pre>{{ state }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried your solution and it works great. Both this and the solution provided by samayo are working for me.